# Plotting 3 live graphs in a single window by using MatLab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I plotted 2 graphs where live data are being plotted successfully. I wanted to use a 3rd graph for experimental purposes.
 
I'm doing this in MatLab.
Here is the code:

```
        fse = 220;
        fsa = 50;
        secBuffer = 10;
        accName = {'F/B'; 'U/D'; 'R/L'};
        accBuffer = zeros([fsa*secBuffer,numel(accName)]);
        final = eegBuffer*5;


        eegCounter = 0;
        plot1 = true;
         conf1 = true;

        if eegCounter == 44
        if plot1
         subplot(3,1,1);
         time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
         h1 = plot(time,eegBuffer);
         legend(eegName, 'Location','EastOutside');
         xlabel('Time (s)')
         ylabel('Voltage (uV)')        

         subplot(3,1,2);
         time = 0:1/fsa:secBuffer-1/fsa;
         h2= plot(time,accBuffer);
         xlabel('Time (s)')
         ylabel('Acceleration (mG)')
         legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

         subplot(3,1,3);
         time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
         h3 = plot(time,eegBuffer);
         xlabel('final');
         ylabel('time');
         %legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

         plot1 = false;

        else
         cell1 = (num2cell(eegBuffer,1))';
         set(h1,{'ydata'},cell1);
         cell2 = (num2cell(accBuffer,1))';
         set(h2,{'ydata'},cell2);
         cell3 = (num2cell(final,1))'; 
         set(h3,{'ydata'},cell3);
        end
```

The value of `final` is `eegBuffer*5`.
`eegBuffer` is defined as `eegBuffer = zeros([fse*secBuffer,numel(eegName)]);`

Since 3rd graph is merely the amplitude of 1st graph, it should be more disruptive graph compared to 1st graph. However it is showing a straight line and I can't tell whether it is plotting live data for 3rd graph.
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

eegBuffer is initialised with a call to function zeros, so it will still be an array of zeros even after multiplication by five (or any number).

Comment: The value of eegBuffer will never be zero. It is calculated on the basis of values of `secBuffer` and `eegName`. The value of secBuffer is 10, eegName is the name of channels: `{'TP9'; 'FP1'; 'FP2'; 'TP10'}`. And eegBuffer is calculated by this formula: `eegBuffer = zeros([fse*secBuffer,numel(eegName)]);`

Comment: if the assignment in your final sentence is the only assignment into variable eegBuffer, then it will be a matrix of zeros. The documentation for function zeros states "zeros(M,N) or zeros([M,N]) is an M-by-N matrix of zeros."

Comment: I got it. Look at `subplot(3,1,1)`. It is similar to 3rd graph and 1st graph is able to plot live data and values of eegBuffer are used in that 1st graph. I'm not understanding why it becomes zero in 3rd graph.

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify how "live data" is being plotted? I assume the code quoted above is in the middle of a for loop, could this code be edited into the question please along with the assignment to eegBuffer?

Comment: No. It isn't in for loop. It is a if block. I'm going to edit the question now.

Comment: Im sorry but you would need to post code which can replicate exactly the effect being described in your paragraph. As it stands, the subplot commands can never be reached. Just try to isolate the minimum code needed to replicate the problem then post that.